# Detect if the WebBrowser Control has timed out?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, session-timeout

is there a way to detect if the current session of the WebBrowser Control (Windows Form C#) has expired from the client?

thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "current session"? A session cookie lifetime? The lifetime of a server-side session?

Comment: I authenticate the user and after some time it forces the logout, so you need to login again. Sorry I don't know how to call this.